# Scrapy twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion, как обойти?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-scraping

Сегодня парсер сайта начал выдавать такую ошибку вместо сбора информации:

```
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://site.com> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection lost.>]
```

Как я понял - проблема в блокировке с той стороны. Как можно обойти блокировку сервера?

P.s. Прокси не помогает(Psiphon)